# Show dialog on top of all other windows

Tags: electron

Is there a way to show the dialog from dialog.showMessageBox() on top of everything?

For example, I'm woking on the notepad and given some event in my Electron application it will open a dialog that should now be the main window for the user to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kinda ugly but you can pass a dummy holder browserwindow which is always on top.

```js
dialog.showMessageBox(
  new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true
  }),
  {
    type: 'question',
    message: 'is on top'
  }
)
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I also tried using dialog.showErrorBox() but the window just won't display

Comment: @C.Reinhold it works with `showMessageBox` but not with `showErrorBox`, as it doesn't have parent window option. However, you can achieve the same look with setting `type: 'error'`

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore. it shows the browser window when you display the dialog

Answer (score 2):

```
const { remote } = require("electron")
dialog.showMessageBox(**remote.getCurrentWindow()**, [options])
```

Set the first parameter

Answer (score 1):

For many use cases, the correct approach will be to pass the existing main window to `showMessageBox`:

```js
dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, dialogOpts)
```

This will make the message box a modal of the main window. The user will need to close the modal before being able to continue using the main window.